# Check if a type is of any from a list of types?

Tags: c#

I need to check whether a generic type parameter is in a set of valid types and have created extension methods to do a run time check:

```
public static bool Is(this Type type, params Type[] types) {
  return types.Any(t => t == type);
}

public static bool Is<T1>(this Type type) {
  return type.Is(typeof (T1));
}

public static bool Is<T1, T2>(this Type type) {
  return type.Is(typeof (T1), typeof (T2));
}
```

With additional methods for T3 - T#...

Usage (in constructor for the generic class):

```
if(!typeof(T).Is<Int32, String, Boolean, CustomClass, Whatever>())
    throw new ArgumentException("T must be a type.");
```

But I would prefer a compile time check (which I don't believe is possible). Failing that, any suggestions on improvements are appreciated.

Comment: Part of me wonders if this would be more suited for [codereview.se]...

Comment: I think you're right. The closest thing to your needs is the [where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384067.aspx) keyword, but it seems too limited for your case. BTW: your exception message is not very helpful :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [User-defined compile-time type constraints in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663342/user-defined-compile-time-type-constraints-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Instead of Linq `Any` in the first method you might as well use Linq `Contains` instead. You can get rid of one lambda.

Comment: If your goal is compile time checking, why does your context allow so many types?

Comment: JeffBridgman - Thanks, didn't know about that.
BartoszKP - Yep, where is "and", I need "or". The real exception message is something better.
JeppeStigNielsen - Contains is better, thanks!

Comment: If your generic type parameter can only be one of a finite set of types then **your code is not generic in the first place**. Rather than trying to figure out how to more elegantly abuse generics, stop abusing generics.

Comment: @EricLippert - Yes, perhaps it's abuse, but in one of the scenarios where I use this I have to wrap an old pre-generics API which returns "object". This "object" is always either one of a predefined set of types. So with this style I can do var myObject = (T)objectParameter;

Comment: And I should add that all of the T:s have the same method which is what I make use of. But they don't implement the same interface and are sealed. So the Int32, String, Boolean bits are more to illustrate that I need to support structs as well as reference types.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a run-time and a compile-time approach. For the compile-time approach I only show how it works for 3 type parameters and for 20 type parameters to show the concept. You can easily add more methods/classes for the number of type parameters you need.

Scroll down to the bottom to see some usage examples.

```
public static class RuntimeTypeCheckExtensions
{
    public static bool IsAssignableToAnyOf(this Type typeOperand, IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        return types.Any(type => type.IsAssignableFrom(typeOperand));
    }

    public static bool IsAssignableToAnyOf(this Type typeOperand, params Type[] types)
    {
        return IsAssignableToAnyOf(typeOperand, types.AsEnumerable());
    }

    public static bool IsAssignableToAnyOf<T1, T2, T3>(this Type typeOperand)
    {
        return typeOperand.IsAssignableToAnyOf(typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3));
    }

    public static bool IsAssignableToAnyOf<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20>(this Type typeOperand)
    {
        return typeOperand.IsAssignableToAnyOf(typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5), typeof(T6), typeof(T7), typeof(T8), typeof(T9), typeof(T10), typeof(T11), typeof(T12), typeof(T13), typeof(T14), typeof(T15), typeof(T16), typeof(T17), typeof(T18), typeof(T19), typeof(T20));
    }
}

public static class CompileTimeTypeCheckUtils
{
    public static IsAssignableToAnyOfWrapper<T1, T2, T3> IsAssignableToAnyOf<T1, T2, T3>()
    {
        return new IsAssignableToAnyOfWrapper<T1, T2, T3>();
    }

    public static IsAssignableToAnyOfWrapper<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20> IsAssignableToAnyOf<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20>()
    {
        return new IsAssignableToAnyOfWrapper<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20>();
    }
}

public class IsAssignableToAnyOfWrapper<T1, T2, T3>
{
    public void OperandToCheck(T1 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T2 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T3 operand) { }
}

public class IsAssignableToAnyOfWrapper<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20>
{

    public void OperandToCheck(T1 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T2 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T3 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T4 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T5 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T6 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T7 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T8 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T9 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T10 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T11 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T12 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T13 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T14 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T15 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T16 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T17 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T18 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T19 operand) { }
    public void OperandToCheck(T20 operand) { }
}
```

Usages:

```
Type someType = ...

// Three example usages of run-time check (using generic types, params and IEnumerable):
if (someType.IsAssignableToAnyOf<string, int, double>())
{
}

if (someType.IsAssignableToAnyOf(typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(double)))
{
}

IEnumerable<Type> enumerableOfAcceptedTypes = new Type[]
{
    typeof (string),
    typeof (int),
    typeof (double)
};

if (someType.IsAssignableToAnyOf(enumerableOfAcceptedTypes))
{
}

// Two example usages of compile-time check:
CompileTimeTypeCheckUtils.IsAssignableToAnyOf<string, int, long>().OperandToCheck(5); // <-- No compile-time error

CompileTimeTypeCheckUtils.IsAssignableToAnyOf<string, int, long>().OperandToCheck(5F); // <-- Compile-time error
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be helpful?

```
List<Type> acceptedTypes = new List<Type>(){typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(long)};
var stringTypeToCheck = "this is a string type";
var intTypeToCheck = 123;
var guidToCheck = Guid.NewGuid();

if(!acceptedTypes.Contains(typeof(stringTypeToCheck.GetType())))
    throw new ArgumentException("incorrect type");
```

You could have a serialized List of the Types stored in a text file if you wanted this to happen on compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should consider this an improvement, but it is an alternative.

After calling `Is` you can chain calls to `Or`. Whenever the chain is complete it's implicitly converted to a `bool` based on whether the given type was found.

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    object x = 1;

    // prints yep
    if (x.Is<float>().Or<double>().Or<int>())
      Console.WriteLine("yep");
    else
      Console.WriteLine("nope");

    // prints nope
    if (x.Is<decimal>().Or<double>().Or<string>())
      Console.WriteLine("yep");
    else
      Console.WriteLine("nope");

    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}

static class Extensions
{
  public static Intermediate Is<T>(this object obj)
  {
    return new Intermediate(obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(T)), obj.GetType());
  }
}

public class Intermediate
{
  public Type ObjType { get; set; }
  public bool Found { get; set; }

  public Intermediate(bool result, Type type)
  {
    ObjType = type;
    Found = result;
  }

  public static implicit operator bool(Intermediate i)
  {
    return i.Found;
  }

  public Intermediate Or<T>()
  {
    if (Found)
      return this;
    else
      return new Intermediate(ObjType.Equals(typeof(T)), ObjType);
  }
}
```